# Need help for c# coding

Tags: c#

This is my class structure

```
public class Customer
{
     List<Address> add = null;
     public Customer()
     {
         add = new List<Address>();
     }

    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Address
    {
        get { return add; }
        set { add = value; }
    }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}


    public void Populate()
    {
        List<Customer> oCust = new List<Customer>()
        {
                new Customer() { EmpID=1, Name="Sonia"},
                new Customer() { EmpID=2, Name="Bill"},
                new Customer() { EmpID=3, Name="Mark"},
        };
    }
```

from the populate method i am populating customer along with address.
when i am populating customer then how to populate address along with it
i am not a advance user so please guide me regarding code that how
`new Customer() { EmpID=3, Name="Mark" new Address{}}`,

please help....thanks

Comment: You might want to consider removing the setter on `Address`, as you can add to the list without changing the entire list...

Comment: Your code is confusing. Should a Customer have a single Adress or multiple ones?

Comment: Is that the best title you could come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void Populate()
    {
        List<Customer> oCust = new List<Customer>()
            {
                    new Customer() { EmpID=1, Name="Sonia", Address = new List<Address>() 
                                        {
                                            new Address { Address1 = "Sonia addr 11", Address2 = "Sonia addr 12", PostCode = "111" },
                                            new Address { Address1 = "Sonia addr 21", Address2 = "Sonia addr 22", PostCode = "222" }
                                        } 
                                    },
                    new Customer() { EmpID=2, Name="Bill", Address = new List<Address>() 
                                        {
                                            new Address { Address1 = "Bill addr 11", Address2 = "Bill addr 12", PostCode = "111" },
                                            new Address { Address1 = "Bill addr 21", Address2 = "Bill addr 22", PostCode = "222" }
                                        } 
                                    },
                    new Customer() { EmpID=3, Name="Mark", Address = new List<Address>() 
                                        {
                                            new Address { Address1 = "Mark addr 11", Address2 = "Mark addr 12", PostCode = "111" },
                                            new Address { Address1 = "Mark addr 21", Address2 = "Mark addr 22", PostCode = "222" }
                                        } 
                                    }
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
List<Customer> oCust = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer() 
    { 
        EmpID = 1, 
        Name = "Sonia", 
        Address = 
        { 
            new Address { Address1 = "foo", Address2 = "bar", PostCode = "pc" },
            new Address { Address1 = "foo 2", Address2 = "bar 2", PostCode = "pc 2" },
        } 
    },
    new Customer() 
    { 
        EmpID = 2, 
        Name = "Bill", 
        Address = 
        { 
            new Address { Address1 = "bill 1", Address2 = "bill 2", PostCode = "bill pc" },
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't need the `new List<Address>`, since it's created in the constructor here...

Comment: @Reed Copsey, perfect, thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer to take it into account. It makes the code shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
List<Customer> oCust = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer() 
    { 
        EmpID=1, 
        Name="Sonia",
        Address = 
        {
            new Address { Address1 = "addr1", Address2 = "addr2", PostCode = "12345" },
            new Address { Address1 = "addr1", Address2 = "addr2", PostCode = "12345" },
            new Address { Address1 = "addr1", Address2 = "addr2", PostCode = "12345" },
        }, 
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Customer() { EmpID=1, Name="Sonia", 
                        Address = new List<Address>() { 
                            new Address() { Address1 = "ADDRESS1", PostCode = "000214"} } 
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate the address the same way you did for Customer like new Customer() { 
EmpID=3, Name="Mark", new Address(){Address1 = "123 Xyz Avenue", Address2 = "Suite 999", PostalCode = "11111"}}